# How changing Yii advanced directory structure

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a project that need some thing more than default yii folder structures.
In yii2 you have something like below to separate backend and fronend of your project.

- advanced

  - common

    - config
    - ...
  - backend

    - view
    - config
    - model
    - controller
    - ...
  - fronend

    - config
    - view
    - model
    - controller
    - ...

  but i need something else.
  In my project there is this parts:
  1-backend
  2-frontend
  3-partners
  and i want some new structure like this:
- advanced

  - common

    - config
    - ...
  - backend

    - view
    - config
    - model
    - controller
    - ...
  - fronend

    - config
    - view
    - model
    - controller
    - ...
  - partners

    - config
    - view
    - model
    - controller
    - ...
      The question is how can i do this?
      thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to `common/config/bootstrap.php`

```
<?php
Yii::setAlias('common', dirname(__DIR__));
//Yii::setAlias('admin', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/admin');
Yii::setAlias('api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api');
Yii::setAlias('frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
Yii::setAlias('backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
Yii::setAlias('console', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console');
```

Comment: Thanks.what about folders and files in **backend** and **frontend** folders? copy them into **partners** folder that created in **advanced** folder?

Comment: @Amin. Yes you can copy them, but if it makes sense in your application. You can also create them using **Gii**.

Comment: That is easy, you may copy them